# Cannot install Roku application from Eclipse IDE

Tags: plugins, roku, brightscript

I could previously install Roku application from eclipse using brightscript plugin. But after I have updated my plugin, suddenly it stopped installation and started showing the msg : "wrong developer mode password". But the password given is correct only. I have done steps like reinstalling plugin, eclipse IDE few times, I have even tried with another PC also, but the result was same. The application was not installing and showing below message. But .zip file was created in the out folder anyway, which I could use to install using browser. But direct installation and package creation is hard to do because of this issue.  Can anybody help me .

[image: this is the msg]

Answer (score 0):

1. Try checking for updates on the Roku and then rebooting the Roku. Sometimes sideloading won't work if your device firmware is out of date or your device hasn't checked for updates in a while.
2. you can also try [using the remote](https://developer.roku.com/docs/developer-program/getting-started/developer-setup.md) to disable and then reenable developer mode, as I've occasionally seen developer mode randomly get disabled or in a non-usable state.

Roku discontinued support for their eclipse plugin on July 15, 2022. (see [this](https://blog.roku.com/developer/eclipse-ide-deprecation) blog post for more information). I highly recommend using the [BrightScript Language](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RokuCommunity.brightscript) extension for VSCode as more modern development environment. (full disclosure, I am the primary developer for that vscode extension).